# How make query builder syntax becoma more simply using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables named laporan, laporankategori_anak, laporankategori_induk seems like this

[image: click here]
I want to access data from kategorilaporan_induk and this is my model

Laporan models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Laporan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'laporan';

    public static function getLaporanUser(int $limit, $id_user)
    {
        $laporan = self::orderBy('waktu_dibuat', 'desc')->paginate($limit)->where('id_user', $id_user);
        return $laporan;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'id_user');
    }
    
    public function getKategori()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\KategoriLaporanAnak', 'id_kategori');
    }
}
```

KategoriLaporanAnak Models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class KategoriLaporanAnak extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'kategorilaporan_anak';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_kategori';

    public function getKategoriInduk()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\KategoriLaporanInduk', 'id_induk');
    }

    public function getLaporan()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Laporan');
    }
}
```

KategoriLaporanInduk Models

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class KategoriLaporanInduk extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'kategorilaporan_induk';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function getKategoriAnak()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\KategoriLaporanAnak');
    }
}
```

And this is my show function on LaporanController

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $laporan = DB::table('laporan')
                    ->join('kategorilaporan_anak', 'laporan.id_kategori', '=', 'kategorilaporan_anak.id_kategori')
                    ->join('kategorilaporan_induk', 'kategorilaporan_anak.id_induk', '=', 'kategorilaporan_induk.id')
                    ->select('*', 'kategorilaporan_induk.nama')->where('laporan.id', $id)
                    ->get();

        return view('laporan.show')->with('laporan', $laporan);
    }
```

The question is, when i want to show the data from table kategorilaporan_induk, i'm using query builder for it.
But i want using Eloquent, so the code will more simply to read.
Do you guys know how the syntax if we use eloquent on it?

Comment: Instead of `DB::table('laporan')->join() ...`, just use `Laporan::join() ...`. `join()` is still valid using Eloquent model instead of the Builder, so your query should still work the same.

Comment: Okay thanks, i have found it